# How can i select item from a list view and assign it to a pictureBox?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

All the items in the listView are images types.
what i want is when i use the keys up/down to move between the items or just click on one of the items to display the item/s in a pictureBox.

```
private void ListView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            String text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Name;
            pictureBox1.Load(text);
        }
```

But i'm getting exception when i click on on the listView since the returning string is empty it's: ""

Maybe the problem is that i clicked on the button Add File and then when i click on the listView it's not yet on a specific item since the control it self not selected yet but the Add File button ?

[image: Images]

Comment: If you get an exception, set a breakpoint and inspect the relevant variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `.Name` to `.Text`

```
string text = listView1.SelectedItems[0].Text;
```

Comment: To be frank, this _answer_ could be a comment though :P

Comment: @CodeCaster it was better provide me relevant meta link, Thanks for suggest comment removed.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297597/what-to-do-with-user-asking-for-upvote-and-accept

Comment: @CodeCaster well I see , there should be some policy for users who ask many questions and got answers but don't mark it. This post is fine but I have seen posts that asker got the answer but did not accept it.